# How to return the property of a single element in an array of nodes or relationships?

Tags: arrays, neo4j

If I have a collection of nodes, each with the property called Name, how do I return the value of that property for the second element?

I've tried these so far:

```
CollectionOfNodes[2](Name) AS Value
CollectionOfNodes[2].Name AS Value
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
(CollectionOfNodes[2]).Name as Value
```

Comment: Take the 2nd element of an collection, grab its name property and alias it as value - too simple :-)

Comment: @StefanArmbruster thanks; next time please include a short explanation directly in your answer, otherwise they tend to end up in the low quality review queue and that's sad. :(

Comment: My math teacher told me that adding brackets means that the enclosed expression is performed prior to any adjacent operators.  I guess the answer above works in the same way, no?